# Image instead of text message in jquery form validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I want to show a success-image instead of the text, but I've no idea how:

```
        success: function(label) {
        label.addClass('valid').text("ok") },
```

(I don't want to do it with css background-image)

Comment: why not use css? you can give background image to error messagetag
(<em> tag).write the customized css for it. or display image inside em on success using .html() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
success: function(label) {
    label.addClass('valid').html("<img src='success-image-path' />") },
```